# preg_replace replacing html tags

Tags: php, html

So

I have code :

```
$wzor = '/^<span class=\"person\">(.*?)</span>/';
$text = str_replace($wzor, '', $text);
```

I want to remove all spans with class person from my text but my code doesn't work

my input is like:

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="label">Spółdzielnia Socjalna Giełda Pracy</span><span class="person">0zł brutto</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><span class="label">LOYD SPÓŁKA AKCYJNA</span><span class="person">0zł brutto</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><span class="label">Loyd 8 Sp. z o.o.</span><span class="person">0zł brutto</span></li>
    <li><span class="label">Loyd 1 Sp. z o.o.</span><span class="person">0zł brutto</span></li>
    <li><span class="label">Loyd 7 Sp. z o.o.</span><span class="person">0zł brutto</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><span class="label">Spółdzielnia Socjalna Giełda Pracy</span><span class="person">0zł brutto</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><span class="label">Spółdzielnia Socjalna Icelandia</span><span class="person">0zł brutto</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><span class="label">Spółdzielnia Socjalna Giełda Pracy</span><span class="person">0zł brutto</span></li>
</ul>bonusbonus
<ul>
    <li><span class="label">Spółdzielnia Socjalna Giełda Pracy</span><span class="person">0zł brutto</span></li>
</ul>bonus
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)?!

Answer (score 1):

The **`^`** at the start forces the match to be at the beginning of the string. Also, there is an unescaped **`/`** in `</span>`

This should work :

```
$wzor = '/<span class=\"person\">(.*?)<\/span>/';
```

Also use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) instead of [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace). ;)

Comment: You can use a different character as delimiter if you need to use '/' in your regexp. And there is no need to escape the quotes. `$wzor = '#<span class="person">(.*?)</span>#'` is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Regular Expressions, you need to use the `preg_replace()` function. Also there was an error in your regex, that did not escape the slash character. This one works:

```
<span class=\"person(.*?)<\/span>
```